# Passing string included dollar signs to -Replace Variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace a sentence in .config file using powershell.

```
${c:Web.config} = ${c:Web.config} -replace
```

'`$BASE_PATH`$\Test\bin`$Test_TYPE`$\WebTest.dll' , 'c:\program Files\example\webtest.dll'

Everytime I try to run the above code I get

> "Invalid regular expression pattern:
>   $BASE_PATH$\Test\bin\$Test_TYPE$\WebTest.dll"
>   at c:\tests\runtesting.ps1 -replace
>   <<<< 
>   $BASE_PATH$\Test\bin\$Test_TYPE$\WebTest.dll

If I don't use the backtick the dollar signs will disappear and some text.

How would I pass dollar signs in a string to -replace?

Comment: Added code to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *about how to escape regexes*. Every special character (special with regards to regular expressions) such as `$` should be escaped with `\`

```
'$A$B()[].?etc' -replace '\$|\(|\)|\[|\]|\.|\?','x'
'$BASE_PATH$\Test\bin$Test_TYPE$\WebTest.dll' -replace '\$BASE_PATH\$\\Test\\bin\$Test_TYPE\$\\WebTest.dll','something'
```

The backtick would be used when the regex would be like this:

```
'$A$B' -replace "\`$",'x'
```

Comment: When I tried your example it worked perfectly, but when i tried it on my code as follow, had no luck.

1) '\$BASE_PATH\$\Test\bin\\$Test_TYPE\$\WebTest.dll' , 'c:\program Files\example\webtest.dll'

2) "\`$BASE_PATH\`$\Test\bin\\`$Test_TYPE\`$\WebTest.dll" , 'c:\program Files\example\webtest.dll'

Comment: Before submitting my comment the second option had the backslashs right after backtick...but now they are not showing.

Comment: Tried the following and worked after adding a (slash + backtick) before a dollar sign and another backslash before an existing back slash, opened and closed the string with double quotes...
-replace "\`$BASE_PATH\`$\\Test\\bin\\\`$Test_TYPE\`$\\WebTest.dll"

Comment: '"\`$BASE_PATH\`$\\Test\\bin\\\`$Test_TYPE\`$\\WebTest.dll"'

Comment: I edited the code so the string `'$BASE_PATH$\Test\bin$Test_TYPE$\WebTest.dll'` gets properly replaced.

Answer (score 4):

To Pass:

```
$BASE_PATH$\Test\bin\$Test_TYPE$\WebTest.dll
```

Change to:

```
`"\`$BASE_PATH\`$\\Test\\bin\\\`$Test_TYPE\`$\\WebTest.dll"`
```

Logic:

- Before every dollar sign enter \`
- Before every backslash enter another back slash \
- Close string with double quotes ""

Comment: This gets my up vote because it offered the simplest and most concise explanation of the issue.

Comment: Upvoted for explaining the logic around escaping $ character

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a bit more background to [stej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206539/passing-string-included-dollar-signs-to-replace-variable#2206656), there are two things going on here:

**1)** While parsing the command, powershell is [expanding the variables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx) in the string arguments to `-replace` (for example, the string `"shell: $ShellId"` will expand the `ShellId` variable, producing `shell: Microsoft.PowerShell`). Using the backtick escape character, or declaring the string with single quotes, prevents this (both `` "shell: `$ShellId" `` and `'shell: $ShellId'` become `shell: $ShellId`).

**2)** The `-replace` operator uses [.NET regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx), where the `$`, `\`, and `.` characters are special language elements. Using the backslash escape character allows special characters to be treated as literal values within the regular expression (e.g. `\$` will match a dollar character, while `$` will match the end of the line). Since `$` is used by both powershell and regular expressions, it has to be escaped twice (using either `` "\`$" `` or `'\$'`).

In this case, another alternative would be to use the [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method, which will perform a case-sensitive replacement:

```
${c:Web.config}.Replace(
  '$BASE_PATH$\Test\bin$Test_TYPE$\WebTest.dll',
  'c:\program Files\example\webtest.dll'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those unfamiliar with the distinction, it is important not to confuse the **backtick** character **(`)** with the **single-quotation** character **(')** in these escapes. For example:

**[SUCCESS]** Double quotes as container with backslash-backtick as escape:

```
PS C:\Temp> 'What is $old?' | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "\`$old", "(New)"}
What is (New)?
PS C:\Temp>
```

**[FAIL]** Double quotes as container with backslash-apostrophe as escape:

```
PS C:\Temp> 'What is $old?' | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "\'$old", "(New)"}
What is $old?
PS C:\Temp>
```

**[SUCCESS]** Single quotes as container with simple backslash as escape:

```
PS C:\Temp> 'What is $old?' | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\$old', "(New)"}
What is (New)?
PS C:\Temp>
```

**[FAIL]** Single quotes as container with backslash-backtick as escape:

```
PS C:\Temp> 'What is $old?' | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\`$old', "(New)"}
What is $old?
PS C:\Temp>
```

Overall, the easiest option may be to use single quotes as the container and a single backslash as the escape: `'\$old'`