# PowerShell using variables in strings passed as parameters

Tags: string, variables, powershell

I have several php files in directory, I want to replace a few words in all files with different text. It's a part of my code:

```
$replacements_table=
("hr_table", "tbl_table"),
('$users', "tbl_users")

foreach ($file in $phpFiles){
    foreach($replacement in $replacements_table){
        (Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object{$_ -replace $replacement} | Set-Content $file 
    }
}
```

It works fine for replacing "hr_table", but doesn't work at all for '$users'. Any suggestion would be nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string is actually a regular expression and so needs to be escaped using '\'. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206539/passing-string-included-dollar-signs-to-replace-variable)

```
$replacements_table= ("hr_table", "tbl_table"), ('\$users', "tbl_users")
```

will work.

Comment: No problem. Please accept an answer by clicking the V besides it. This markes the question as answered and gives credit to the person helping. :)

Answer (score 2):

The dollar sign is a special regular expression character, matches the end of a string, you need to escape it. Escaping a character in regex is done by a '\' in front of the character you want to escape. A safer method to escape characters (especially when you don't know if the string might contain special characters) is to use the Escape method.

```
$replacements_table= (hr_table', 'tbl_table'), ([regex]::Escape('$users'), 'tbl_users')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping "`$`' with a backslash: `'\$users'`
The $ symbol tells the regular expression to match at the end of the string. The backslash is the regular expression escape character.

Answer (score 0):

try using double quotes around your variable name instead of single quotes

**EDIT**

Try something along these lines ....

```
$x = $x.Replace($originalText, '$user')
```

Comment: That would not work, as he wants the string '$users' replaced. Using double quotes would mean that Powershell interprets it a variable.

Comment: I also tried "`$users", but it doesn't work either. Any other ideas?

Comment: I know when I've wanted the $ to be used (ie - not designating a variable), I've had to put it in single quotes. like so '$' + "$someVariable". But I'm not sure how to approach your problem because you're using the variable containing the $ as a parameter for another function

Comment: having said that I've used $_.Replace(origStr, newStr) in some of my script and I've got $ symbols in my newStr. I'll add another answer with an example of the code I used

Comment: I also tried "`$users" along with combinations of quotes, but no luck. I would guess Powershell actually reads the variable as '$users' the first time but when it's used in the loop it's already 'unwrapped' from the string and will be interpreted as a variable. Could you try to rewrite it in a more verbose way? Perhaps without using pipes to try to see exactly where it fails and what the replacement variable contains in each step?