# PowerShell: -replace words in variable with leading $ symbol

Tags: shell, powershell, replace, powershell-2.0

**My objective:**
I want a string variable to be altered by a function that replaces some keywords in the string.

**The problem:** Keywords needing replacement are identified by a leading **$**.

**My code:**

```
function ReplaceStuff{
    param([string]$text=$(throw 'text is required.'))
    $text -replace  "`$uid" , $UserId
}
```

*Note: The ReplaceStuff function is in another .ps1 file that is referenced by the main script, but I don't think that has anything to do with the problem, as this works fine without the $ symbol*

```
$mainText = ReplaceStuff($mainText)
echo $mainText
```

**OUTPUT:** (nothing different than the text in the original variable)

> blah blah blah $uid

I've been looking around the web first. While I have found similar question, nothing has actually worked for me. The closest thing I found to matching my exact problem is the addition of the tick (`) to the $, but it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use single quotes, that makes the string literal and escape the $ regex token with a backslash:

```
$text -replace  '\$uid' , $UserId
```

And this previous question: [Passing string included dollar signs to -Replace Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206539/passing-string-included-dollar-signs-to-replace-variable)

Comment: `$` is an anchor in regex......

Comment: This does not work for me. :(

Comment: Good point, I think you need to escape it with a \ in regex. @Matt do you know?

Comment: It could be worth noting that this is PowerShell 2.0

Comment: It looks like you need to both escape the character and use single quotes to make the string literal, so try either \ or ` (backtick) inside a single quoted string.

Comment: \ appears to be the key. Thanks everyone. I'll accept this in 4 minutes once SO allows me to!

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting Don't forget the single quotes. You have to worry about the regex and powershell parsers for that to work. Could just use the `.Replace()` method as well since that skips the regex overhead. The dupe covers this as does what Mark links to.

Comment: I've got the single quotes going now. In the time I was working on solving this myself, I had tried .Replace(), but the same problem persisted.